# Missing method exists in DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, method-missing

It seems I'm missing the method `LambdaExpression.CompileToMethod` under the namespace `System.Linq.Expressions` that exists in the referenced assembly and I cannot understand why.

When I'm including this method in my codebase:

```
public static void CompileLambdaToMethod(LambdaExpression lambdaExpression, MethodBuilder methodBuilder)
{
    lambdaExpression.CompileToMethod(methodBuilder);
}
```

Visual Studio says the method `CompileToMethod` doesn't exists and I get the following error when compiling:

> Error CS1061  'LambdaExpression' does not contain a definition for 'CompileToMethod'

I also cannot find the method if I follow the definition of `LamdaExpression` in Visual Studio.

The method does exist in the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728258(v=vs.110).aspx

Also, the method exists in the DLL if I inspect the DLL that I'm referencing by following the reference in Visual Studio and opening the abosolute path (at the top inside the `#region Assembly`) in dotPeek.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a mismatch in target framework versions between the DLL and your project. Can you check if this is the case?

Comment: Did you check the Target framework in  project properties ? Cause this method does exist for >= .net 4.0 only